# Amazon Lex Multiple Messages

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I have a bot that gets information from three apis. Right now I aggregate all this information in the message and send it all at once:

```
{
sessionAttributes,
dialogAction: {
   type: 'Close',
   'Fulfilled',
   message
}
```

Is there a way to send out the information as I get it?
The end result will be three different messages one after another without any input from the user.

Comment: Did you make any progress with this eventually?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible natively with Lex. AWS Lex follows a request/response model and so will only process responses directly related to a user request. **The recommended approach is aggregation as you have stated in your question.**

**However**, depending on your integration strategy, you could send multiple messages by bypassing Lex and sending the results from your APIs directly to the user.

e.g.

1. User: "Hey Lex. Get my things"
2. Lex

   1. Asynchornously calls each API
   2. Responds to user: "I'll have them sent to you now"
3. API 1 to user: "Here is result 1"
4. API 2 to user: "Here is result 2"

This strategy would work with integrations like Slack, where messages can be received across the same channel from multiple sources.